# How to cure my 8 week old kitten's orange diarrhea?

Tags: cats, health, diet, diseases

4 days ago I adopted a little kitten who looked really sick and didn't eat for days. She seems 8 weeks old and doesn't have a mother. When I fed her hours later, she started leaking yellow diarrhea and it didn't stop, so I took her to the vet. He gave her two shots.

After that she was in pain and refused to eat, but hours later I was able to feed her. But now she has orange diarrhea. I read about it and it said maybe she has a liver or a bile problem. Please, could you explain it to me? I'm really afraid I really want to save her.

Comment: be sure the kitten has clean fresh water at all times and feed only canned food,when you feed her you need to give her little food each time and feed her once every two hours.try your best to make her eat slow as eating too fast might be a possible cause for the diarrhea,give her small portions of food multiple times during the day.please take a look at the linked Q&A for possible solutions to the problem.